# How to get max string per group in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I please need help returning the maximum string in a column for a given group of columns in Polars. I have an example of the process working for maximum number, but not for string.

```
import polars as pl

pl.__version__
# '0.15.2'

d_int = pl.DataFrame({
    "g": ["a", "a", "b"],
    "v": [1, 2, 3],
})

# works
(
    d_int
        .groupby(["g"])
        .agg([
            pl.col("v").min().alias("v_min"), 
            pl.col("v").max().alias("v_max")]
            )
)


d_str = pl.DataFrame({
    "g": ["a", "a", "b"],
    "v": ["x", "y", "x"],
})


# returns nulls
(
    d_str
        .groupby(["g"])
        .agg([
            pl.col("v").min().alias("v_min"), 
            pl.col("v").max().alias("v_max")]
            )
)
```

The first calculation works, but the second returns the following (with nulls).

```
┌─────┬───────┬───────┐
│ g   ┆ v_min ┆ v_max │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ str   ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ a   ┆ null  ┆ null  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ null  ┆ null  │
```

Comment: This was fixed a few days ago https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5735

Comment: Thank yo very  much. I am new to Polars, so I figured it was me. Now I just wait for the version to propagate out. If you submit that as answer, I'll close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was added in `polars==0.15.3` and should work as expected.

Comment: I tested it and it worked great! Thanks!!